# Javascript traversing DOM PHP created table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have created an HTML table with PHP with contents from a SQL query. Inside this table, there is a column with drop-down menus. I want to change the value in the column next (where $outputPoints is the default value) to it when the drop down has been changed.

The HTML echoed in PHP with some sample data:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div style = \"padding-right:15px;\">
        <select class=\"form-control\" onchange=\"showValue(this)\">
            <option value=\"1\">$result[1]</option>
            <option value=\"2\">$result[2]</option>
            <option value=\"3\">$result[3]</option>
        </select>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>$outputPoints</td>

</tr>
```

The above is called iteratively. I'm not sure should I be adding id's here and what those Id's might be? The quotation marks are escaped as it sits inside an echo statement. I can remove these if it makes things clearer.

The javascript:

```
function showValue(obj)
{

var newValue = obj.value;
    console.log(newValue);
obj.parentNode.parentNode.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = newValue;
}
```

I thought I understood the logic of traversing the DOM but I cannot see an update. Console.log is printing correctly. What am I doing wrong/not understanding?

Much thanks for your help!

Comment: If you can help me improve my question, please let me know. I have a good handle on PHP, JS and jQuery. Just been tearing my hair out over this one.

Comment: why are there slashes in that HTML? or $values for that matter? Does the PHP not generate actual HTML?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans This is inside an echo statement in PHP. The quotation marks needs to be escaped.

Comment: @Mike I think its quite obvious that this is being echoed in a string using double quotes, hence the variables in the statement

Comment: it's not obvious because of the words "the HTML echoed ..." - I read that as "this is the result of the echo", in which case this would be weird. If that's the actual code, then more code around it is needed to show how the echo happens (EOL string? concats? etc)

Comment: You're probably right there Mike. That was in fact what succeeded the echo statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this with jQuery is quite easy -

```
$('select[name="foo"]').change(function() {
    var currentVal = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).html(currentVal);
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/bzoaefw9/)

You could also go a little more directly -

```
$('select[name="foo"]').change(function() {
    var currentVal = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest('td').next().html(currentVal);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jay. I know this technique and use it elsewhere in my program. However, these nodes don't have names. Are you recommending that they should have names? In that case, could you please recommend a naming scheme for elements that are generated to display results of a SQL Query?

Comment: Any form element should have a name, if not you'll have problems when submitting them. You could make the name be anything that you want, something descriptive of the query or results. FYI, I found that your JavaScript works fine, have you checked the console for errors? [Added your script here](http://jsfiddle.net/bzoaefw9/1/) @JohnoAvocado

Comment: that is a good point about the forms. I wasn't thinking ahead.  The script is working now. Thanks for your help.